# Dismiss dialog before new activity

Tags: android

I'm creating a game in which the user picks an image and a puzzle is created. The first screen lets the user pick an image and a dialog appears on-click, which lets the user choose the difficulty. After ImageSelection, the image is shown for three seconds in the ShowImage Activity, after which GamePlay starts. I created the dialog as follows:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

class GameDialog {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static int difficulty;
    static AlertDialog d;

    public static AlertDialog showDifficulties(Context c, final int img_id) {

        mContext = c;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Select difficulty")
               .setItems(R.array.my_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // the 'which' argument contains the index position
                   // of the selected item

                       // default difficulty is 3
                       int difficulty = 3;

                       // options for difficulties
                       switch (which) {

                           // when the user clicks 'easy'
                           case 0:
                               difficulty = 3;
                               System.out.print("DIFFICULTY");
                               System.out.println("" + difficulty);

                           break;

                           // when the user clicks 'medium'
                           case 1:
                           difficulty = 4;

                           System.out.print("DIFFICULTY");
                           System.out.println("" + difficulty);
                           break; 

                           // when the user clicks 'hard'
                           case 2:
                           difficulty = 5;

                           System.out.print("DIFFICULTY");
                           System.out.println("" + difficulty);
                           break;
                           }

                       // send intent with image id and difficulty 
                       // to ShowImage activity
                       Intent start_game = new Intent(mContext, ShowImage.class);
                       start_game.putExtra("img_id", img_id);
                       start_game.putExtra("difficulty", difficulty);
                       d.dismiss();
                       mContext.startActivity(start_game);
               }
        });

        d = builder.create();
        return d;

    }
}
```

This went pretty well (and worked). Secondly, in GamePlay I want the user to be able to change the difficulty from the menu, after which the app starts ShowImage again, but with the corresponding chosen difficulty. 
Here is the code for GamePlay:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.reset_game:
            //TODO: resets the game to initial shuffled tiles
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        case R.id.difficulty:
            // lets user change the difficulty of the game
            // pass the index to the dialog and show the dialog
            Dialog d = GameDialog.showDifficulties(GamePlay.this, selected_image);
            System.out.println(selected_image);
            d.show();

        case R.id.quit:
            // returns the user to ImageSelection
            intent = new Intent(GamePlay.this, ImageSelection.class);   
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However, the app throws the error "GamePlay has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView (etc) that was originally added here"
I did some research and thought it could maybe be caused by not closing the dialog in the ImageSelection Activity. So I took some steps and added this to my **ImageSelection Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    d.dismiss();
    super.onPause();

}
```

Yet this did not fix my problem :c
My question therefore is, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix the error? The goal is to get the same dialog (from the separate class I created) in two different activities. 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I now added "d.dismiss();" to the dialog class as suggested by Hany Elsioufy, however this did not fix the problem.

Comment: The error message mentions `PhoneWindow$DecorView`, but I don't see neither `PhoneWindow` nor `DecorView` in your code.

Comment: I honestly do not know what it means too, because I see nothing related in my code. But when I Googled it, I found it possibly being related to not dismissing a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

Turns out I had to add return statements to my switch-case within onOptionsItemSelected():

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.reset_game:
            //TODO: resets the game to initial shuffled tiles
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.difficulty:
            // lets user change the difficulty of the game
            // pass the index to the dialog and show the dialog
            Dialog d = GameDialog.showDifficulties(GamePlay.this, selected_image);
            System.out.println(selected_image);
            d.show();
            return true;

        case R.id.quit:
            // returns the user to ImageSelection
            intent = new Intent(GamePlay.this, ImageSelection.class);   
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;

        default: 
            return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
// handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.reset_game:
        //TODO: resets the game to initial shuffled tiles
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

    case R.id.difficulty:
        // lets user change the difficulty of the game
        // pass the index to the dialog and show the dialog
        Dialog d = GameDialog.showDifficulties(GamePlay.this, selected_image);
        System.out.println(selected_image);
        d.show();

    case R.id.quit:
        // returns the user to ImageSelection
        intent = new Intent(GamePlay.this, ImageSelection.class);   
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

In the above code,there is no break statement.
please use break statement when you use switch case.

Comment: Oh! And then what do I put into the onOptionsItemSelected to return? Because I understand it's a boolean.

Comment: add this line after switch end return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution! Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Define AlertDialog d; as an Instance Variable, and then before any startActivity or Intents write:

```
d.dismiss();
```

Comment: Could you explain this further? When I put this in my, let's say GameActivity, I get an error about a null-pointer reference, because it calls 'dismiss' on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: you want to dismiss the dialog before going to another activity, then just declare AlertDialog d in an instance variable, then you are saying AlertDialog d = builder.create(); well replace it with d = builder.create(); then call d.dismiss(); before startActivity() method

Comment: I see. The problem is, my dialog is in a separate class. The startActivity is also in that class, which means if I call d.dismiss() within that class, the dialog will never show when it's called in the Activity. How do I fix that?

Comment: just before mContext.startActivity(start_game); write d.dismiss(); in ur case I think dialog.dimiss(); which is the clicked dialog

Comment: I did as you said, but unfortunately the app still throws the same error :c